# Split large database using Lotus Domino replica

Tags: lotus-notes, database-replication

I've a 34Gb database (on server A), and i want to delete part of its documents to improve performance, after creating a replica of database itself.
Followed these steps:

- create a local replica of database
- deleted several documents from original database

I want to be sure to recover deleted documents into original database, if needed, using replica database.
So i try to use a *pull* into database from local replica, or a *push* from replica to database.

Nothing happened, 0 documents added, i'm not able to "re-import" documents.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

They're not supposed to come back! Replication goes both ways, and the most recent change to a document overwrites an older version, but deletion always wins.

Well... almost always.

When a document is deleted in one replica, a 'deletion stub' is left in its place. As long as that stub exists in the replica, a version of that document in another replica will not replicate back. The stub blocks it.  That's why deletion wins.

But stubs are purged after a period of time called the 'purge interval'. The default purge interval is 30 days.  After a stub has been purged from a replica, deletion can't win any more because there is nothing left to block an old revision from replicating back from another replica.  The thing is, usually this is a Bad Thing. Usually when documents are deleted, you want them to stay deleted. You don't want them to reappear just because somebody kept a replica off-line for 31 days.

Now, there are some ways that you can try and control this process carefully, purging stubs and using something else (e.g., selective replication settings) to prevent deletions from coming back *except when you want them to*. There are ways to try, but one slip up with one setting in one replica, and **boom**! Bad things happen. And that includes *any* replica, including ones that you are not controlling carefully. It's a bad idea. I agree completely with @Karl-Henry on this.

Also, selective replication is evil and should be avoided at all costs. That's just my opinion, anyhow, but I have a lot of scars left over from the days before I came to that conclusion.

Here are two Lotus tech notes about replica stubs and the purge interval: [Purging documents in Lotus Notes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21091379), [How to purge document deletion stubs immediately](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21095683). Please use what you learn from these technotes wisely. I urge you not to to use this knowledge to try and construct a replication-based backup/restore scheme!

Comment: I second the evil that is selective replication

Answer (score 0):

I would be very careful using a replica as an archive like that. I could see someone replicating the wrong way, and that would cause some issues...
I have designed some archive solutions for several of my big databases here at work. I simply have a separate database (same design) designated as archive. I then have a manually triggered or scheduled agent (different in different databases) that identify the document to be archived and moved them from the production database to the archive. I then have functions to move documents back into production of needed.

Comment: thanks, but what about IDs documents? Using your archive method, do you preserve the same IDs? I need it, as granted by replication method

Comment: Do you mean the Notes document ID? It will not be preserved, but you should never write code that relies on that. It could change even in the original database, for example if you get replication conflicts. So in a well written application, that should not be a problem.
And I don't suggest that you modify the UniqueID of the documents when you copy them over to the new database, even if you can do that. The day you try to copy the documents back to the production database, Bad Things will happen. If the deletion stub is still around, the new document will go *poof* (get deleted at once).

Comment: Your are right, but my application starts 13 years ago, and often documents are related each other using their @documentUniqueID (doesn't depends by me :-) ). So, if i change that, i loose all reference. This is why i'm thinking about replica

Comment: A little bit depending on exactly how yor application is designed (just response and response-to-response, or also non-responses tied to the main document) you could still write an archive agent. Retrofit the documents with a field called for example 'OriginalUNID' and populate it with the UniversalID of the document. Any response doc get an additional field called 'OriginalParent' where you store the value of $REF.
When you archive documents, start with the parent document, copy it over, then recursivly copy all child documents over and use the MakeResponse method to restore the structure.

Comment: When you restore to the archive, you do the same in reverse. But do not mess with the UniversalID, I promise it will come back an bite you. When I started at my current work, they had done exactly that. Later, when they tried to restore documents back into production, those documenst came over, just to get deleted within minutes, at the next resplication...